# "Deep loading" with LoadWith

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a table structure, each table with a primary key field named as "ID" and foreign key names matching their parent table's primary key. Therefore, the tables below have relationships where their primary key appears in another table and the first field in any table is it's primary key:

```
Category
--------
CategoryID
Title


CategoryList
------------
CategoryListID
CategoryID
ListID


List
----
ListID
Title


DataPoint
---------
DataPointID
RecordedDateTime


DataPointValue
--------------
DataPointValueID
DataPointID
TheValue
```

The above is a many-to-many join between Category and List, via CategoryList. It is also a one-to-many join from List to DataPoint, DataPoint to DataPointValue.

Using C#/LINQ and given a List of the CategoryID values, I would like to retrieve:

All the List entries attached to the Category I have ID's for. With those List entries, I would like to take the most recent 1 DataPoint, as ordered by RecordedDateTime Descending. From there I would like to retrieve every DataPointValue attached to the DataPoint.

The LINQ I have is:

DBDataContext context = new DBDataContext(ConnectionString);

```
        context.LoadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
        context.LoadOptions.LoadWith<DataPoint>(p => p.DataPoints.OrderByDescending(p.RecordedDataTime).FirstOrDefault());

        // this next line is how I get the list of category IDs, but don't worry about that...
        List<int> categoryIDs = (from TreeNode n in nodes
                                 select Int32.Parse(n.Value)).Distinct().ToList();

        var lists = from i in context.List
                                         join ci in context.CategoryLists on i.ListID equals ci.ListID
                                         join p in context.DataPoints on i.ListID equals p.ListID
                                         join v in context.DataPointValues on p.DataPointID equals v.DataPointID
                                         where categoryIDs.Contains(ci.CategoryID)
                                         orderby i.Title ascending
                                         select new
                                         {
                                             List = i,
                                             DataPoint = p,
                                             DataPointValues = p.DataPointValues
                                         };
```

But this is obviously not working - the LoadWith is causing me issues. Could someone explain how to construct the LoadWith so that it will cause as few SQL queries as possible to retrieve this (admittedly large) amount of data, please?

Many thanks,

Matt.

Answer (score 3):

You asked this a month ago, but here's an answer anyway...

There are a few issues here:

- Once you set the LoadOptions property on the context, you can't change it.  You should create and configure your DataLoadOptions object, and when you're done, assign it to the context.
- LoadWith specifies what children get automatically loaded with the parent.  So `loadOptions.LoadWith<DataPoint>(p => p.DataPointValues)` would automatically load the DataPoint's children, and not wait until the DataPoint.DataPointValues (or whatever you name it) property is accessed.  LoadWith makes the loading non-lazy (eager).
- AssociateWith allows you to filter and order the in children that automatically-loading relationship.  For example `loadOptions.AssociateWith<DataPoint>(p => p.DataPointValues.OrderByDescending(v => v.TheValue))` would sort the DataPointValues by value.

And finally, I'd probably break up your query into two, just to make it easier.

```
// first setup a DataPoint -> DataPointValue relationship in your DBML
// then set up the DataPointValues to automatically load with DataPoint:

dataLoadOptions.LoadWith<DataPoint>(dp => dp.DataPointValues);

// then assign the load options to the context here

// First query
List<int> listIDs = context.CategoryLists
        .Where(cl => categoryIDs.Contains(cl.CategoryListID))
        .Select(cl => cl.ListID)
        .ToList();


// Second query(ies) - this isn't the most elegant, but simple is usually better :)
List<DataPoint> dataPoints = new List<DataPoint>();

foreach (int listID in listIDs)
{
    DataPoint foundDP = context.DataPoints
        .Where(dp => listIDs.Contains(dp.ListID))
        .OrderByDescending(dp => dp.RecordedDateTime)
        .Take(1)
        .SingleOrDefault();

        // Remember, at this point DataPointValues will already be loaded into the DataPoint

    if (foundDP != null)
        dataPoints.Add(foundDP);
}
```

Anyway, that's a longwinded answer that you may or may not even need!  Ah well, it's practice for me, I guess.  Hope it helps.

***EDIT:***

Sorry, started thinking about this...

You could possibly do this instead (cleaner, faster):

```
loadOptions.LoadWith<List>(l => l.DataPoints);
loadOptions.AssociateWith<List>(l => l.DataPoints.OrderByDescending(dp => dp.RecordedDateTime).Take(1));
loadOptions.LoadWith<DataPoint>(dp => dp.DataPointValues);

// assign the LoadOptions here,     
// then:

List<DataPoint> dataPoints = context.CategoryLists
        .Where(cl => categoryIDs.Contains(cl.CategoryID))
        .Select(cl => cl.List.DataPoints)
        .ToList();
```